# Assignment to variable when they are grouped with assign

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How can we found that a assignment to variable is fast using assign statement as compared to another method? Please explain.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109045/what-is-the-efficiency-of-an-assign-statement-in-progress-4gl

Answer (score 2):

Of course it depends on what it is that you are assigning and how many individual statements you are grouping together.  But a simple example of comparing the difference is easy enough to put together:

```
define variable i as int64 no-undo.

define variable x1 as int64 no-undo.
define variable x2 as int64 no-undo.
define variable x3 as int64 no-undo.
define variable x4 as int64 no-undo.
define variable x5 as int64 no-undo.

etime( yes ).
do i = 1 to 10000:
  assign
    x1 = i
    x2 = i
    x3 = i
    x4 = i
    x5 = i
  .
end.
message "with a grouped ASSIGN:" etime.

etime( yes ).
do i = 1 to 10000:

  x1 = i.
  x2 = i.
  x3 = i.
  x4 = i.
  x5 = i.

end.
message "without ASSIGN:" etime.
```

FWIW:

1. On a modern release of Progress I would not expect to see much difference.  Even in a benchmark designed to show such things. Quite a few things which were slow and needed to be optimized 30 years ago no longer need that kind of micro-optimization.
2. I would expect that any difference that still exists is even harder to find in realistic code. (The example above is not very realistic.) Sure, there are probably a few specific cases where it is a useful performance optimization. But I wouldn't use "performance" as an excuse to be doing this. The link that Austin points to - [what is the efficiency of an assign statement in progress-4gl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109045/what-is-the-efficiency-of-an-assign-statement-in-progress-4gl) provides better reasons.

Comment: measuring performance with only 10 thousand iterations and etime gets a downvote from me ;-)

Comment: The numbers are consistent as you add zeros.  I checked ;). And, hey! I upvoted your answer even though you used pre-processors :(. I like that you always remember to provide a link to the abldojo

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this pointless benchmark - which at a minimum you should have put in your question to start asking something meaningful - out there for further debate:

```
def var dt as datetime no-undo extent 4.
def var ic as int no-undo initial {&sequence}.

def var cc as char no-undo.

&scoped-define iterations 10000000

dt[{&sequence}] = now.

do ic = 1 to {&iterations}:

   cc = "hello".

end.

dt[{&sequence}] = now.

cc = "".

dt[{&sequence}] = now.

do ic = 1 to {&iterations}:

   assign cc = "hello".

end.

dt[{&sequence}] = now.

message 
   interval( dt[2], dt[1], "milliseconds" ) skip
   interval( dt[4], dt[3], "milliseconds" )
   .
```

https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5ef603c34b1a0f40c34b8c63

For 10,000,000 (ten million) iterations of the above nonsense, the assign version takes 2392 ms and the non-assign version takes 2469 ms -> that's a saving of 77 milliseconds -> the plain performance is irrelevant and heavily outweighed by factors mentioned in Tom's earlier answer about readability and intent.

You /may/ have a case in which this is relevant, in which case you will need to do your own measuring.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of advantages to using the keyword, and you can definitely read more in detph here:
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/assign-statement.html

As for my personal experience, I can say this:
I don't have benchmarks to be sure they're actually faster, but I'd say the benefits of using the ASSIGN statement are more related to transaction/behavior control. With the assign statement you can use the NO-ERROR option, for example, which allows you to treat possible problems with the values you're using.

I'd say it's also a matter of language aesthetic. Single line assigns without the keyword will do the job. But it will probably look sloppier.